# What's going on

Tags: behavior, feeding, snakes

Trying to feed ball python. If I put my hand in tank to spray water for humidity water mix soil or any reason the snake shows no interest and goes to hide head. But if the rat is in tank at the same time fingers become target and main focus. Its repeatedly striking but not coiling around the prey to kill and eat. This is a recent problem that I have never seen. Will rush to strike back off and just stare ready to strike if close enough. Is it warning because its to close when snake dosnt want to eat? Close to 3 pounds and has been eating year round at least once every other week. There are no signs of affected eyesight from left over skin from shedding

Answer (score 1):

Those are defensive strikes. Your fingers being the focus is probably just a result of the smell of food plus warm wiggly things that might be a threat. Sounds like your ball is just going on hunger strike, which is pretty common for them. Keep offering food on your normal schedule. Don't offer every day, stick to every other week. This could go one for multiple months, monitor his weight and unless there is a dramatic decrease, he'll likely be fine.

Also, sounds like you're feeding live. If so, I would recommend not doing that. Bulk frozen rodents are cheaper and much less hazardous to your snake.